# Why doesn't sizeThatFits work with UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I have a simple class that contains two labels and a line in a stack:

```
class TestView: UIView
{
    let label_A     = UILabel()
    let label_B     = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect)            { super.init(frame: frame);     setup() }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder);  setup() }
    func setup()
    {
        let view_BG     = UIView()
        let view_LineH  = UIView()

        // Configure
        view_BG.backgroundColor = .white
        view_BG.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        view_LineH.backgroundColor = .gray

        label_A.numberOfLines = 0
        label_A.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        label_A.textColor = .red
        label_B.numberOfLines = 0
        label_B.textColor = .blue
        label_B.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2)

        label_A.text = "TestA"
        label_B.text = "Experiment with Swift standard library types and learn high-level concepts using visualizations and practical examples. Learn how the Swift standard library uses protocols and generics to express powerful constraints. Download the playground below to get started."

        // Assemble
        self.addSubview(view_BG)
        view_BG.addSubview(label_A)
        view_BG.addSubview(view_LineH)
        view_BG.addSubview(label_B)

        // Layout
        view_BG.constrain_edges(to: self)
        label_A.constrain_edges(to: view_BG, excludingEdge: .bottom)
        label_B.constrain_edges(to: view_BG, excludingEdge: .top)

        view_LineH.constrain_height(1)
        view_LineH.constrain_left(to: view_BG)
        view_LineH.constrain_right(to: view_BG)
        view_LineH.constrain_topToBottom(of: label_A)
        label_B.constrain_topToBottom(of: view_LineH)
    }
}
```

When I call sizeThatFits, it just spits the height back at me:

```
let v = TestView()
let s = v.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 200, height: 10000))
// s is (200, 10000)
```

How can I calculate the desired height with a given width?

Comment: It makes sense that it gives you that back. all your constraints in `TestView` are all constrained to the edges. But the thing you havn't set the frame of `TestView` yet. So given an unknown frame size of everything inside how can you determine the correct frame size to contain all of them? You can't.

Comment: Then what is the point of specifying a *width* and a *height* in sizeThatFits? If I was only specifying one, it would be ambiguous. Even if I add something like: v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: columnWidth, height: 100) before the sizeThatFits call, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `.systemLayoutSizeFitting()`:

```
    let tv = TestView()

    let targSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 10000)

    let fitSize = tv.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: 1000, verticalFittingPriority: 1)

    print(fitSize)

    // prints "(200.0, 245.0)" in my playground
```

I don't have whatever you are using for `.constrain_edges` stuff, so here is the actual view class I'm running:

```
class TestView: UIView
{
    let label_A     = UILabel()
    let label_B     = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect)            { super.init(frame: frame);     setup() }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder);  setup() }
    func setup()
    {
        let view_BG     = UIView()
        let view_LineH  = UIView()

        // Configure
        view_BG.backgroundColor = .white
        view_BG.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        view_LineH.backgroundColor = .gray

        label_A.numberOfLines = 0
        label_A.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
        label_A.textColor = .red
        label_B.numberOfLines = 0
        label_B.textColor = .blue
        label_B.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2)

        label_A.text = "TestA"
        label_B.text = "Experiment with Swift standard library types and learn high-level concepts using visualizations and practical examples. Learn how the Swift standard library uses protocols and generics to express powerful constraints. Download the playground below to get started."

        // Assemble
        self.addSubview(view_BG)
        view_BG.addSubview(label_A)
        view_BG.addSubview(view_LineH)
        view_BG.addSubview(label_B)

        view_BG.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label_A.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label_B.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view_LineH.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Layout
        view_BG.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view_BG.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view_BG.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view_BG.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true


        label_A.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        label_A.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        label_A.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        label_B.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        label_B.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        label_B.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        view_LineH.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        view_LineH.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_BG.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        view_LineH.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label_A.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        label_B.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_LineH.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        view_LineH.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange, it's giving me (0, 285.5). To make it compile, I had to the parameters to:
let fitSize = c.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)

Comment: Don't know if has anything to do with constraints, but I added the actual class I'm running to test this.

Comment: Hmmm.... possibly version difference? I'm running this in an Xcode 8.2.1 playground. If you're using Xcode 9 / Swift 4, that might matter.

Comment: I'm not sure. Actually, I made a mistake, I also set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth property of each label to get my result. If I remove that line, it goes back to being (200,10000) for me. Maybe it's a difference in the environment?

Comment: Comment-out your `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property assignments, and try changing the `verticalFittingPriority` to `UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel` (which is probably `.fittingSizeLevel`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155449/discussion-between-donmag-and-goldenjoe).